# How do you understand the kWh that the power company charges you for?

Tags: mains, energy

I really didn't know how to phrase this question. But here are the details.

First I understand the simple 10 x 100 W for 1 hour is 1 kWh.

But what I want to know is at what time interval does the power company calculate my usage?

The simple answer is the hour, but that is too simple because I'm sure they know when I turned all my lights on for 10 minutes with a total wattage of 2 kW. Does that mean they charge me 0.33 kWh?

If I turn on a 100 W bulb for 10 minutes every hour for 6 hours. What is the power company going to calculate my usage at? Would it be 16.6 watts each hour? Do they take samples every second and then calculate the kWh from that?

I've read different analogies but one I kind of thought of was a tank that gets measured and emptied every hour. If you turn on your 100 W light bulb for 10 minutes then 16.6 watts is added to the tank. If I then boil my kettle for 10 minutes at 3200 W, 533.33 watts are added to the tank. So in that hour I used 0.5 kWh.

Comment: If I travel at 100mph for 1 hour, or I travel at 600mph for 10 minutes, either way I traveled 100 mph-hours and if I my bill is calculated based on mph-hours, I pay the same amount. It doesn't matter what the sampling frequency is. (mph-hours are also called "miles")

Comment: ... And 1 Watt is in fact 3600 Joules per hour (1 J/s) so it is that simple. kWh is akin to distance, total energy used, and kW is like the speed, or rate of energy usage.

Comment: @user253751 - you're over complicating that, your bill is based on **miles travelled**, doesn't matter how much your speed varied, whether you stopped & started etc.

Comment: @JohnU the point that user was making is that electricity usage is the same: doesn't matter how much it varies/starts/stops.

Comment: `what time interval does the power company calculate my usage` - every moment. Now, for the old-school analog meters that is basically infinitesimal (or at least in theory Planck time (the smallest unit of time describable (not measurable) by physics)). For modern digital meters it is usually several milliseconds to several hundreds of milliseconds (I've seen meters that measure 10 times per second and ones that measure 100 times per second). Leaving this as a comment because the answers below are already good

Comment: "If I then boil my kettle for 10 minutes at 3200 W, 533.33 watts are added to the tank." - No, you added 533.33 J (joules) to the tank of water. Please get your units right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A couple of points:

- **k** for kilo, **K** for kelvin.
- **W** for watt.
- **Power** (W or kW) is an instantaneous measurement.
- **Energy** is power × time is charged in **kWh** (= kW × h).

Now to your questions:

- The energy meter **integrates** the power used with respect to time. If you have the old spinning disc type of energy meter you would see the disc speed up in proportion to the load. A newer digital meter will usually have an LED indicating measurement pulses. This will blink at a faster rate when demand is increased.

[image]

*Image source: [Free Images Live](http://www.freeimageslive.co.uk/taxonomy/term/36/0?page=4).*

> I'm sure they know when I turned all my lights on for 10 minutes with a total wattage of 2 kW. Does that mean they charge me 0.33 kWh?

Correct. 2 kW × 1/6 hours = 2/6 = 1/3 kWh.

> If I turn on a 100 W bulb for 10 minutes every hour for 6 hours. What is the power company going to calculate my usage at? Would it be 16.6 watts each hour?

0.1 kW × 1/6 hours = 0.0166 kW**h**. (It's **multiplied** by time - not **per** unit time.)

> Do they take samples every second and then calculate the kWh from that?

That's probably about right. The mechanical meters are continuous. The digital meters will sample and may measure each cycle of the mains (50 or 60 times a second).

> I've read different analogies ...

Try thinking of a tank that has fuel in it and a meter measuring what's consumed. You turn on the light and it consumes 16.6 μl/s. You switch on your kettle and it consumes 3.2 ml/s. The meter just records the fuel used. It doesn't care weather you used it all on the first day of the billing period or if it was a constant rate throughout.

Comment: Technically speaking, meters measure energy directly, multiplying voltage, current, and time. This is stored in time intervals, and the derivative is taken to calculate power.

Comment: @LShaver What meter is that? Link to an example that works like that?

Comment: @david  The meter is a tiny electric motor that continuously winds a needle around. Instantaneous volts x amps is watts, and watts x time is power. The amps is sampled using proximity of the supply cable as an intentionally inefficient inductor coil, and the meter is calibrated by adjusting the proximity. Domestic meters ignore power factor, commercial meters charge for low power factors at high rates (because it disrupts supply management).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, and at what point in that process are we "measuring energy directly" and "taking the derivative" to calculate power. To me what you describe is measuring power directly (with the inductive connection to the motor) and integrating to calculate energy (by allowing the needles to wind around as the motor turns).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, Link to an example that works like that?  Note: modern meters are not induction meters, and most induction meters didn't "use the derivative to calculate power", but that's not the point: just link to the meter you are talking about, so people can see.

Comment: @david I was on mobile before so didn't explain well. I used to work at a [meter manufacturer](https://www.quadlogic.com/) and authored a whitepaper on this, which is no long online. Basically, because V and I have a sample rate less than the ac frequency, when they're multiplied there's an inherent time quantity stored because the sample rate is fixed -- so the energy is known, but nothing about the phase angle is known. Apparent power is calculated by dividing through by the sample rate, and the reactive power is calculated by shifting V 90deg, multiplying by I, and dividing by time.

Comment: Note that this is just like an analog meter where the speed at which the dial spins has to be known in order to know the power, requiring a secondary measurement circuit.

Comment: The link in [another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/675813/93845) actually shows this process. [Section 4.2.1.2](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa637a/slaa637a.pdf?ts=1690769286902&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsolution%252Felectricity-meter) -- P is sum over samples of v x i, *divided by the number of samples*. Then energy is this power quantity, times the number of samples.

Comment: This answer needs improving a bit. 1) Sample rate is _much more_ than 50/60Hz for a smart meter, more in the order of a few kHz - very few domestic loads are nicely linear anymore. 2) The LED isn't 'measurement pulses', it's just a pulse every 1 Wh of energy consumed.

Comment: @david  The question is completely generic -- basically "How does the power company figure out the kWh to charge me when my usage is changing all the time". The answer is "the meter adds it up as it goes along". The actual meter to accomplish that is not relevant: they all have to come up with the same value anyway. I didn't choose the word "derivative" -- the charge is based on integration over time, not differentiation. Even smart meter displays show recent average use over hour/day/week/month, they do not show instantaneous power (which would probably scare the users silly).

Comment: @LShaver, the meters I am familiar with sample at much greater than the line rate. We already have a link to one such meter. We already see that not all meter types are the same: it would be good to get a link to (1) a meter like you describe. and (2) a meter like Paul_Pedant describes

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Our smart meter shows instantaneous power (or at least, averaged over a small number of seconds, hard to tell exactly as it is also delayed) - so if I turn on the electric oven, the reading will jump up several kW within a few seconds.

Comment: @david see my additional comments above. The TI meter referenced in another answer works as I describe.

Comment: @LShaver the TI meter samples at 2-4K, not "less than the AC frequency", and does not "take the derivative to calculate power". I think it's fair to assume that the meters you worked with work as you described: it would be good if you could link to that information.

Comment: @Sanchises While 1 optical metering pulse per 1 Wh is the most common, there are residential meters set to 10 or 7.2 Wh/pulse, the latter to match rotating-disc meters. This is labeled on the front as the _Kh_ value

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Do commercial meters explicitly charge you for _low power factors_, or do they simply measure _apparent power_ (kV⋅A) and charge you based on that?

Comment: @Nayuki  I was estimating future demands for a low-carbon world, in a UK distribution company with 2.3M domestic customers and about 60,000 commercial meters (but a big user like Heinz could have 20 metered feed points at voltages up to 132KV). I got 48 half-hourly readings per meter per day, and every reading had a separate value (with 0.2kVA accuracy) for real, reactive and capacitative load. Each bespoke tariff had punitive costs for excess low power factors, and varied for time of day, and discounts for companies that would allow short-notice power cuts to preserve other supplies.

Comment: @Nayuki In the US, large industrial customers will pay a rate per kWh, another amount based on kVARh and a monthly demand charge based on, typically the highest 15-minute average kW and a similar charge based on kVAR. All of these rates may also vary per time of day, having easily 4 periods (super-off-peak, off-peak, peak, super-peak).

Answer (score 8):

The term kilowatt-hour is a bit misleading in that it doesn't measure over the span of hours.  Power meters measure almost continuously, and integrate the power measurements into an overall energy measure.

An old-style electrical meter had a motor that would spin at a rate proportional to the power (not current -- the actual power) being consumed, and a gear train that ran a bunch of dials on the face of the meter; those dials would be read by the power companies once a month.

Today's meters mimic that electronically.  I'm not sure how it's done, but if I were doing it today, the cheapest way to do it with good enough accuracy is to sample the voltage and current at several kilohertz, multiply them into instantaneous power, and then sum up that instantaneous power to mimic continuous integration.

If the meter is working correctly then:

- If your house uses 100W all the time, without variation, for a whole month, then at the end of the month you'll get billed for 72 kW-h.
- If your house uses no power at all except for using 3kW for exactly one day out of the month, then at the end of the month you'll get billed for 72 kW-h
- If your house uses no power at all except that at noon on one day some device that consumes 72kW tries to kick in for one hour, then in a typical residential installation a fuse will blow, because that's asking for 300 amps (in North America) which is silly for a residence.

Comment: I can't see what's misleading in the term kilowatt-hour. It is just the right name for the physical quantity "energy". And why do you introduce the strange (wrong) notation "kW-h"? What is this good for?

Comment: @Elec1 while the hyphen in the notation is not not technically correct (or at least, less common?), there *is* an option to use a dot to signify multiplication (such as m·s) which might help someone distinguish between the separate units being multiplied together more easily. Perhaps a more correct notation would be "kW·h", "kW*h", or similar.

Comment: Is "revolutions per minute" of e.g. a dental drill misleading if it's actually only used for a few seconds? Is "miles per gallon" misleading if trips are normally less than one mile?

Comment: In now way does the unit "hour" in kWh imply anything about the time span it's measured over. If you say you're driving at a speed of 80 km/h, it also does not imply anything about how long you're actually driving (e.g. you could be driving for minutes, not an hour).

Comment: Turn off everything for vacation. Come home. Plug in the EV to charge at 48A (far more than most people need for home charging), crank up the AC (20A) and two people jump into full blast hot showers using a (absolutely crazy, but people use them) 120A tankless water heater and you've got 48+20+120A = 188A @ 240V = 45kW going at once. Which is absolutely nuts. And **still** way below 72kW.

Comment: Some people get confused between "kilowatt" and "kilowatt-hour", hence the question. Maybe we should bill people in megacalories, which they already know as a unit of energy (1 kWh = 0.860421 Mcal)

Comment: It's as misleading as mph or km/h unless you also think cars suddenly teleport 60 miles every hour or you cannot drive cars for 10 minutes or any amount of time less than an hour.

Comment: @pjc50 Hard no to calories. Instead, take inspiration from some natural gas utilities that bill their customers in megajoules (MJ). Example: https://www.canstarblue.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Billing-MJ.png

Answer (score 8):

Texas Instruments has a series of reference designs for [Electricity meter
Products and reference designs](https://www.ti.com/solution/electricity-meter)  which can provide guidance for how microcontroller based electronic meters can be implemented. Where the reference designs include:

1. The hardware to sample voltage and current.
2. Source code for the microcontroller.

Section *4.2.1.1 RMS Voltage and Current* of [Implementation of One- or Two-Phase Electronic Watt‑Hour Meter Using MSP430i20xx](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa637a/slaa637a.pdf) contains the following which indicates the sample rate of the raw mesasurements for one design:

> As described in the previous sections, voltage and current samples are obtained from the ΣΔ converters at a sampling rate of 4000 Hz. All of the samples that are taken in 1 second are kept and used to obtain the
> RMS values for voltage and current for each phase.

Answer (score 5):

There's a nifty device somewhere on your house/building that keeps track of all the energy going through it: the electric meter. It monitors energy usage and continuously increments a counter for your utility company to read. Typically, they read the meter once every month (more or less, depending on a variety of factors including budget and geography) and bill you for the difference since the last time they read the meter.

If you turned off absolutely everything, the meter would not increment its counter. If you did this for an entire billing cycle, the company would see the same value on the prior reading as the current reading, and you wouldn't be billed for any usage during that time period. (You would, however, be billed for base costs, which you can think of as minimums to cover things like infrastructure, maintenance, and overhead.)

Power (measured in Watts) is voltage multiplied by current. A device, such as your refrigerator, will have varying power requirements based on what it's doing at the time. It might be running the compressor and various other things, and consuming its max power at a given moment. If you measure the power usage at that time, consider that as its *instantaneous power* usage. When it reaches a low temperature, it shuts off the compressor and might only power a minimum of electronics to monitor the temperature, and be at a very low power, which has a different instantaneous measurement. It is of little use to know these values by themselves, because the *duration* your appliance stays at these power usage levels is what's important to charging you for energy usage. Thus, the time component ("h" for hours) is tacked onto the kW unit, resulting in "power over time" or, simply put, energy.

I think the heart of your question is in knowing that the power company, i.e. meter, doesn't "sample" your power usage periodically, but rather does so continuously. You may recall a decade or more ago electric meters had physically spinning wheels and dials?

[image: Electric meter animated GIF]

They simply tap off a small portion of the current flowing past the measurement point and increment the dials accordingly. The more power you use, the faster the increment speed.

These days most meters are more efficient, have few or no moving parts, and often transmit the reading electronically/wirelessly to the property management or utility company for billing.

Comment: How are you resetting your meter? d:^)

Comment: @Transistor Shhh, it's a special accessory! :)

Comment: kWh meters [are more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter#Electromechanical) than "tap off a small portion of the current" since they continuously integrate the instantaneous product of voltage and current.  Thus they only bill you for actually consumed energy (even if the voltage fluctuates), not for reactive power.

Comment: @user107063 I'm aware of that. I'm simplifying for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

### The month

Your concept seems to revolve around "sampling periods". It's not like that. It's more like an analog "flow meter" e.g. when you pump gas. Movement of fluid turns the meter. Likewise movement of current turns the meter "disc".  *There is no way to "game" the sampling period since there isn't one*.

And once a month a human comes and reads the meter.   No just kidding - these days they put some electronics *in front of* that "disc" so they can electronically collect the kWH count once per month.

But they do better than that, actually. They take hourly snapshots - most power companies use 30 minute or 15 minute, even.  Why? Several reasons.

- When you buy a service upgrade, they don't upgrade the service drop wire if they can avoid it; they just monitor this data to see how much that drop wire is "heating the sky" and upgrade it when that makes financial sense.  They get to do that because they operate under different rulebooks.
- Time-of-day tariffs, obviously, e.g. [an hour-by-hour tariff in Chicago](https://youtu.be/0f9GpMWdvWI?t=328).
- Solar metering, if applicable.
- Some tariffs make extensive use of this data. For instance Duke Energy, heavy on hydro and nuclear base load, offers an optional, peak-based tariff that is *bonkers*. Your monthly bill is $7 x your highest KiloWATT (not kWH) peak hour and that's it.*  It's optimized for homes with electric heat. But combine that with some smart panel / [Load Sheds](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/277803/47125) to squash all your peaks, and you could have a ridiculously cheap energy bill.

* Well, there's a per-kWH rate but it's under 1 cent, so it's a negligible part of the overall bill. Even if you used battery tech to completely flatten yourself to a continuous load, it'd be half your bill at most.  They suspend this sweet deal during summer afternoon peaks, so people who aren't [Technology Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI) may pay or swelter.

And for reference, a North American 100A-200A service  trips the main breaker at 24kW ($168) or 48kW ($336) i.e. that's the highest your *peaking charge* could possibly go.

Comment: Different locations and even different customers get different rates, so I'm not clear how you equated 24 kW to $168 and 48 kW to $336. Heck, I pay a different rate for usage between 4 and 9 pm than for usage during the rest of the day.

Comment: @ThePhoton  I'm referring to the peaking charge of $7 per kW.  But I didn't cover the fact that the per-kWH charge stops being a penny a kWH in summer afternoons, and rises to more normal 12 cents/kWH. (with the peaking charge **too**). That's where they getcha.  But I would just shut the house down during those times and fry [like poor Alec from Technology Connections :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI)

Answer (score 3):

Remember all those distance/rate/time problems you learned about in grade school? They were a preview of calculus, specifically of integrals and derivatives.

We have distance = velocity x time. Likewise, we have energy = watts x time. More generally, for distance and energy, instead of saying ‘times’, we’d say *is the integral of* (rate) over (time).

That is, power is a *rate* (specifically, watts = joules/s) just like km/h is a rate.

Likewise, kWh is an *integral* of rate, just like km is an integral of km/h for distance travelled. Their math works the same.

Your speedometer gives you instantaneous rate, while the odometer continuously tallies distance travelled, regardless of fluctuations in rate.

Likewise, a utility meter measures watts and tallies the watt-hour (again, technically joules*60) consumption, doing so *continuously* regardless of moment-to-moment rate variations. Like the odometer, the meter’s tallying action *integrates* power (that is, rate) over time.

The speedometer and the utility meter are doing a bit of calculus. Moment-to-moment rate variations don’t matter: the meter sees them and they just get added to the tally. For any given time interval then, we have single number that represents the average rate. The Mean Value Theorem tells us so.

Meter tallying vs. load is easier to visualize with a mechanical spinning-disk meter, which tallies power use by counting the disk revolutions. You can tell when a high-power device is on: the disk spins faster, adding more revs to the tally.

There’s another household spinny-wheel device that measures consumption: your water meter, which also tallies use with a spinning wheel that measures water flow rate.

Gas meter? Same thing, a spinny thing measures gas volume and tallies it.

So I’ve said that the instantaneous power rate doesn’t affect the meter tally. That’s a bit more nuanced now that the newer ‘smart’ meters have arrived.

Smart meters can separate energy usage by day-part. This allows billing at different rates depending on the time of day, a scheme intended to encourage shifting high-power loads (like dryers, ovens, pool pumps and especially A/C units) to off-peak hours. You as a consumer have some control over this and it *could* save you money.

Cynically, time-of-use billing is a way to extract more revenue from ratepayers, subject to the whims of your utility and forces you cannot control (like weather and politics.)

Answer (score 3):

## It doesn't matter.

If you travel at 2000mph for 10 minutes you go 330 miles.

If you travel at 100mph for 10 minutes, you go 16.7 miles. If you do it 6 times you go 100 miles. It doesn't matter how long of a rest stop you take in between.

If you shower at 20 gallons/hour for 10 minutes you use 3.3 gallons.

If you shower at 1 gallon/hour for 10 minutes you use 0.167 gallons. If you do it 6 times you use 1 gallon. It doesn't matter how long you take to dry your hair in between.

If you turn on 2kW of lights for 10 minutes, you use 0.33 kWh.

If you turn on a 100W bulb for 10 minutes, you use 0.0167 kWh. If you do it 6 times you use 0.1 kWh. It doesn't matter how long you huddle in the dark in between.

Answer (score 1):

To borrow the car analogy from @user253751, you are being charged simply for the miles travelled.

If you get in your car and drive at 100mph for 1 hour you go 100 miles.
If you drive 10 cars at 10mph for an hour you (cumulatively) drive 100 miles.

The odometer in your car *doesn't care* how fast you went for how long, if you stopped & started & changed speed etc. etc. it just *counts up the miles*.

Your electricity meter does exactly the same - the more power flows, the faster it counts. Older analogue ones are continuously counting (there is no time interval), newer ones are sampling at some given interval (likely *fractions* of a second) which will introduce a very very small amount of averaging from one millisecond to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is mostly correct.

The time interval the electricity meter calculates over is called infinitesimal: it's non-zero, but very small. It continuously accumulates (totalizes) power times this tiny interval.

That is: the electricity meter is computing - whether electromechanically or electronically - the *time integral* of real power. Real power as opposed to imaginary power - and there is such a thing!

Answer (score 0):

Any competently designed power measurement device will include an analog low pass filter which will continuously integrate current and voltage. This you can think of the time interval as being infinitely small (see calculus).

Answer (score 0):

Most power companies charge for other things apart from the basic kWh:

But first thre rate for kWh can vary during the time of day - for home use it just tends to be a day rate and a night rate as the load is lower at night, so they make it cheaper so people move some of their use to the night time.

However, for business or commercial users, the story gets more complicated, there are varying rates for kWh based on the time of day and also for the amount you use - larger users can get discounts - and these discounts can be significant if you agree to drop your load when the power company has too large a demand so they effectively cut you off at peak demand times - which is why you can get a serious discount.

Then there are the charges for  reactive power, which can also be significant so many large users have power factor control units fitted to control the power factor: if you think you like maths and electrical theory then it is a fun exercise :)

Then some power companies also do a Triad charge which looks at a combination of factors - we used to make sure we avoided pulling power then but we had several methods of generation so we balance dour loads to avoid that.

If you ask your power supplier for the detailed information of how the charges are calculated they will oblige. Good fun putting that into a spreadsheet - did this to work out the "best" power provider as we had a complicated scenario as not only were we interested in the charges for use, we had to factor in the rates they were going to pay for our surplus we generated...